# Correct way of initializing stored properties? - Xcode 8.3.3 / Swift 3

Tags: swift, class

I have a class like this:

```
class Card: CustomStringConvertible {

// Init values
var id: UUID = UUID.init()
var shown: Bool = false
var image: UIImage
var sound: String = ""

init(image: UIImage) {
    self.image = image
}

init(sound: String) {
    self.sound = sound
}

init(card: Card) {
    self.id = (card.id as NSUUID).copy() as! UUID
    self.shown = card.shown
    self.image = card.image.copy() as! UIImage
    self.sound = card.sound
}
```

Why do I get an error ("Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties") in the init(sound: String) method. As far as I read it's important to set an initial value, what I did.

Comment: The `image` property is undefined ...

Comment: Expand  the error in the issue navigator and you'll see: `'self.image' not initialized` – The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `init(sound: String)` you don't assign any value to image.
Since this property is mandatory and none optional.

You have two options, make the property optional:

```
var image: UIImage? = nil
```

Or assign an new image object to it:

```
init(sound: String) {
    self.sound = sound
    self.image = UIImage()
}
```

Comment: With my approach I wanted to init the values for the use in this method: fileprivate func randomCards(_ imageData: [UIImage], soundData: [String]) -> [Card] {
        var cards = [Card]()
        for i in 0...imageData.count-1 {
            let image = Card.init(image: imageData[i])
            let sound = Card.init(sound: soundData[i])
            cards.append(contentsOf: [image, Card.init(card: image)])
            cards.append(contentsOf: [sound, Card.init(card: sound)])
        }
        cards.shuffle()
        return cards
    } How do I have to change this for your solution?